# Communication between two hc 05 Bluetooth modules not working

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, arduino-nano, hc-05

I Have a problem with the connection between two hc 05 modules. The bluetooth modules are paired using AT commands. But when I run the code I cant get any data from the reciever. The bluetooth modules blink together but no data is displayed in the reciever. This is for a RC car that is controlled by a remote controller.

This is the code for the remote

```
void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write("Hello!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I have made sure all the baudrates are 38400 and when I just type the numbers in the serial monitor of the reciver it works fine. I have switched the bluetooth modules but It didn't work either. Boath remote and car has TX - RX and RX - TX wiring.

This is the code of the reciever

```
int data = 0;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    data = Serial.read();

    Serial.print(data);
  }
}
```

I used softwere serial as well but It gave me the same result. The reciever is an arduino mega and the transmitter is an arduino nano
Pls help.
Thank you.

Comment: reduce your code to sending and receiving one fixed byte

Comment: I tryied that but It didn't work, it didn't receive the data on the reciever. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: ok I changed it 